# Kernel module semaphore issue

Tags: linux-device-driver, semaphore, kernel-module, pci-e

I have written a kernel module, It I am using a `semaphore`.
In `init_module`, `semaphore` is initialized and calling semaphore `down() call` once.
In `device` file `read()` function I am having semaphore `down()` call followed by `memcpy()`.
In interrupt handler only semaphore `up()` call;

There is a user application which only reads from `devfile` and displays;
The hardware will give interrupt after every frame data transferring completed.

The problem is in executing the functions respectively.
After inserting the module, `semaphore` value is `-1`.
According to my understanding when i execute the user application it is waiting at `read()` function (trying to down the semaphore again).
When interrupt handler is executed semaphore is up once (now semaphore value 0).
Then read function also success.

Here the problem is the first read function is displaying garbage values and next onwards correct.

So please any one can say why this garbage values in first read..? Expected value is first frame data.....

Comment: Can you post the code snippet? Are you using `down_interruptible` after `sema_init` in `init_module`? Need more clarity!

Comment: yeah in init_module after sema_init i am using down_interruptable call..